# Times / Rotas on SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, crosstab

Hello  I am trying to show a rota in sql but now stuck

I have tried a few things but seem way off the mark!

Essentially my data returned is

```
Name            | Role   | RotaDate              | StartTime             | EndTime 
Joe Bloggs      |Cleaner |2017-01-09 00:00:00.000|1900-01-01 19:00:00.000|1900-01-02 07:15:00.000
Joe Bloggs      |Cleaner |2017-01-11 00:00:00.000|1900-01-01 19:00:00.000|1900-01-02 07:15:00.000
```

So this is a shift on 9th Jan from 7pm - 7:15am.  There are other dates / times etc but this is just a snippet.

I would like it returned as the following (assuming he has shifts on the 11th as well for example

```
Name-------|Role-------| 09/01----------| 10/01 | 11/01

Joe Bloggs | Cleaner | 19:00-07:15 |           |19:00-0715
```

Any help would be appreciated (both this and the layout!

My attempt was

```
select name, role, date,convert(datetime, r.timeFrom+' - '+convert(datetime,r.timeTo) as Shift 
max (CASE when r.rotadate='2017-01-09' THEN timeFrom else 0 END) as '2017-01-09',
max (CASE when r.rotadate='2017-01-10' THEN timeFrom else 0 END) as '2017-01-10'
from rota
```

where rota date between '2017-01-09' and '2017-01-13'

Comment: please read "How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?"
https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting - also have a look at the "Code format" function when posting a question/answer.
makes it easier to understand your question - thx in advance

Comment: what have you tried so far to solve your problem? show us your approach. stackoverflow is not a free code writing service

Comment: What you mean by `both this and the layout!`??

Comment: What you need here is a `PIVOT`. Google for it. It's a bit complex, but there are plenty of reading available on the net.

Comment: appreciate the comments my attempt was

Answer (score 1):

Firstly i created sample data and converted the data in to required format

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #temp
;With cte(Name,[Role],RotaDate, StartTime ,EndTime )
AS
(
SELECT 'Joe Bloggs','Cleaner' ,'2017-01-09 00:00:00.000','1900-01-01 19:00:00.000','1900-01-02 07:15:00.000' Union all
SELECT 'Joe Bloggs','Cleaner' ,'2017-01-11 00:00:00.000','1900-01-01 19:00:00.000','1900-01-02 07:15:00.000' 
)
SELECT NAME
    ,[Role]
    ,LEFT(RotaDate, 10) AS RotaDate
    ,StartTime
    ,SUBSTRING(EndTime, CHARINDEX(' ', EndTime, 1) + 1, LEN(EndTime)) AS EndTime
    ,STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT '- ' + CAST(SUBSTRING(StartTime, CHARINDEX(' ', StartTime, 1) + 1, 5) AS VARCHAR(19)) 
                                 + '-' + CAST(SUBSTRING(EndTime, CHARINDEX(' ', EndTime, 1) + 1, 5) AS VARCHAR(19))
            FROM cte
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '') AS StartTimeENDTime
INTO #temp
FROM cte
```

Then using pivot we get desired result

```
SELECT NAME
    ,[Role]
    ,ISNULL([2017-01-09],'') AS [09/01]
    ,ISNULL([2017-01-10],'') AS [10/01]
    ,ISNULL([2017-01-11],'') AS [11/01]
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM #temp
    ) AS Src
PIVOT(MIN(StartTimeENDTime) FOR RotaDate IN (
            [2017-01-09]
            ,[2017-01-10]
            ,[2017-01-11]
            )) AS PVT
```

Result

```
             NAME       Role        09/01         10/01     11/01
            -----------------------------------------------------------
            Joe Bloggs  Cleaner    19:00-07:15              19:00-07:15
```